# How to get the output of intermediate layers which are not connected via Sequential() function?

Tags: keras, output, layer

I am new in Keras, but I worked with pure tensorflow before. I am trying to debug some of the following network (I will just copy a fragment. Loss function, optimizer, etc are unimportant to me for with this code)

```
#Block 1 (Conv,relu,batch) starts with 800 x 400
main_input = LNN.Input(shape=((800,400,5)),name='main_input')
enc_conv1 = LNN.Convolution2D(8,3,padding='same',activation='relu')(main_input)
enc_bn1 = LNN.BatchNormalization(axis=1)(enc_conv1)

#Block 2 (Conv,relu,batch) starts with 400 x 200
maxp1_4 = LNN.MaxPooling2D(strides=2)(enc_bn1)
enc_conv2 = LNN.Convolution2D(16,3,padding='same',activation='relu')(maxp1_4)
enc_bn2 = LNN.BatchNormalization(axis=1)(enc_conv2)
enc_conv3 = LNN.Convolution2D(16,3,padding='same',activation='relu')(enc_bn2)
enc_bn3 = LNN.BatchNormalization(axis=1)(enc_conv3)
concat1_5 = LNN.concatenate(axis=3,inputs=[enc_bn3,maxp1_4])
```

I have seen some examples of how to do it adding each operation to a Sequential() function (for example as the one explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919436/keras-getting-output-of-intermidate-layers) but with the add() function. Is there a way to check the output of each layer without adding them to a model itself (as it can be also done with Tensorflow, making a session)?

Answer (score 1):

The best is to make a model that outputs those layers:

```
modelToOutputAll = Model(main_input, [enc_conv1, enc_bn1, maxp1_4, enc_conv2, enc_bn2, enc_conv3, enc_bn3, concat1_5])
```

For training, keep a model with only the final output:

```
modelForTraining = Model(main_input,concat1_5)
```

Both models are using the exact same weights, so training one changes the other. You use each one for doing what you need at the moment.

- Train with `modelForTraining.fit(xTrain,yTrain, ...)`
- See intermediate layers with `modelToOutputAll.predict(xInput)`